# Looping in C after determining ending number?

Tags: c, loops, unix, for-loop

I'm looking for a way, in C, to loop through numbers after determining how to divide the number up (i.e. if I have to split the number list into 4 loops, I want to start the first loop at numbers 0 through 24, the second loop, 25 through 49, etc.)

```
int ch, count = 0, thread = 4, div = 0;

FILE *fp = fopen("number_list.txt", "r+");

do
{
    ch = fgetc(fp);

    if( ch == '\n')
    count++;

} while(ch != EOF);

div = (count/thread);
```

What I'm looking to do is build a for loop after this to read the first 25 numbers, then do a specific action (like a square for each number), then in the next loop, pick up where the last loop left off in terms of number count and number in file.

I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: Why do you want to split it into groups...are you trying to implement threading?

Comment: @Arvindsinc2 at some point, yes, I will need to use multithreading

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) for (j = i*25; j < i*25+25; j++) /* do something */ `

Comment: If you are doing this for multithreading, be sure to take the cacheline size into account.You will get a tremendous amount of thrashing if your threads are competing to update the same cache line.

Comment: @kaylum that seems to be working except that the number count is now starting at 25 and ending at 124

Comment: You forgot to check whether `fopen` succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Odly enough, with the help of @Kaylum I was able to work it through. I used his portion, and modified it a little to get what I needed:

```
int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        for (j = ((i*25)-25); j < (i*25-25)+25; j++)
        {
            printf("Square Array Number: %d\n", j);
        }

        printf("-----ProcessID %d-----\n", i);

    }
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. Your choice of starting at `1` instead of `0` (of course is up to you), but is quite non-standard. Additionally, the algebraic equivalent of `(i*25-25)+25` is simply `i*25`.